# Fatal error: Index out of range UITableView indexPath.row

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am getting the index out of range error when trying to load an image from a url for the indexPAth.row.

I have the struct model correct to grab the URL from the Json response. And I can get the URL in the debugger window, but as soon as I try to grab the image in cellForRowAt: , that's when I get the Fata error.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return redditData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RedditTableCell", for: indexPath) as! RedditTableCell

        let post = redditData[indexPath.row]

        // uncomment this print statement and I get the fata error
        //print(post.data.preview?.images?[indexPath.row].source.url)   

        // uncomment this and in the debugger it will show the images URL path
        //print(post.data.preview?[0].source.url)  

        // each cell has only one   mainImage 
        print(post.data.preview?.images?[0].source?.url)  // prints the image url path, for each cell.
        cell.thumbnail.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.data.thumbnail!))
        cell.mainImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: (post.data.preview?.images?.source!.url)!)) 
        // images is an array [images]

        return cell
    }
```

Here is the debugger output:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/all/.json
Optional("https://external-preview.redd.it/aF3ZkA26B3LsRG6ugjJTHAgn5uL_3y_iniPkFMGTZqY.jpg?auto=webp&amp;s=1554c0af19a4e1776a29878c4c0c1cb1c1324c15")
Optional("https://preview.redd.it/cy8jp6qvvb631.jpg?auto=webp&amp;s=cc5a0c15d130a4c54f33963ccce4cd1588871e85")
Optional("https://preview.redd.it/b39b3dgalb631.jpg?auto=webp&amp;s=19b137dc245a243acda7c6a08b7d7e3d5b2acda6")
2019-06-24 13:37:46.137915-0500 MyRedditBrowser[15273:1933069] Task <77A8D26A-6460-48A2-9140-381470ABB7DF>.<1> finished with error - code: -1002
2019-06-24 13:37:46.140059-0500 MyRedditBrowser[15273:1933066] Task <77A8D26A-6460-48A2-9140-381470ABB7DF>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=default, NSErrorFailingURLKey=default, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <77A8D26A-6460-48A2-9140-381470ABB7DF>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <77A8D26A-6460-48A2-9140-381470ABB7DF>.<1>, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000016d0600 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}} [-1002]
```

So what super basic thing am I missing? And sometimes I don't see any NSURLError at all ??

Comment: `post` is already the data for the row. You don't also want to use the indexPath to get the image within the row's post.

Comment: do I put images in a bracket? [images] like that? but I get errors that way too.

Comment: post.data.preview?.images?.source!.url. gives me this error: Value of type '[Image]' has no member 'source' , but source IS a member.

Comment: You are saying `post.data.preview?.images?[0]`. If `images` is an empty array, you will crash.

Comment: You are also using an exclamation mark. That too is an invitation to crash (in a different way).

Answer (score 0):

You are saying

```
print(post.data.preview?.images?[indexPath.row].source.url)
```

If `images` is empty or its `count` is smaller than `indexPath.row+1`, you will crash. So put a condition beforehand to check that.

```
if let count = post.data.preview?.images?.count, count > indexPath {
```

Comment: Oh and then in the bracket I would have my cell.mainImage = image at that indexPath!

Comment: It's unlikely this is the correct solution. It will fix the crash but it doesn't really address the underlying issue. `post` is already the row specific data. You shouldn't be using `indexPath` at all to access the images within `post`.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm sure you're right; I was just looking at the crashing line and trying to explain the crash. Feel free to write a better answer.